# How can I disable data: URIs in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I can't stop some people in my family from visiting sites with bad stuff on them but I can try to minimize the damage (and the amount of time I have to constantly take to fix the subsequent problem).  Evil data: URIs are causing me major headaches at the moment.  Most of the extensions I can find to block specific URIs assume they start with http or https and don't even let me enter the protocol (and so won't block data URIs).  The "Simple Blocker" extension seemed to do the trick at first, but not before it lets some things slip through (redirects, popups, etc).  Any help on blocking or disabling data: URIs would be very highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Same story. I wish I could just disable data URIs support altogether or for a particular website that only uses data URIs to load intrusive annoying  unblockable ads pictures advertising sites full of malicious content.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages/links can no longer open data URIs in Chrome 60+ (late July 2017), Opera 47+ and Edge. Users can still download from them or navigate directly to them from the address bar. A third-party extension is no longer needed.

Sources: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669602927312896, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594215